How to activate extension and process opened tabs when window loads?
I'm writing a linter extension for VSCode. I want to process files and report diagnostics for all visible editors.
Currently, I'm subscribing to window.onDidChangeActiveTextEditor and workspace.onDidChangeTextDocument to analyze documents. The problem: When window loads with preopened tabs, those tabs are not analyzed, and I haven't found an event that would detect such tabs for me to handle. I've tried window.onDidChangeVisibleTextEditors but it doesn't fire on window load too. My activation event is onLanguage. I've tried onStartupFinished, but it didn't change anything.

in you activate function iterate over all open tabGroups and process the files and setup the hooks to be called when things change

Thanks @rioV8, all I needed was to iterate over window.visibleTextEditors in activate.
